# Storing Array in memcache using PHP , array element gets unset after sometime from memcache

Tags: php, arrays, memcached

I am saving an array of 29 elements in a memcache key 'getBannerInfo' . The array is something like :

```
[bannerid] => 5059
[campaignid] => 2687
[contenttype] => png
[storagetype] => url
[filename] => 
[imageurl] => http://testanalyst.org/c2687/13381938962791_50x50.png
[htmltemplate] => 
[htmlcache] => 
[append] => 
[width] => 50
[height] => 50
[weight] => 1
[url] => http://www.google.com
[alt] => new image
[bannertext] => New image
[description] => test image alt text 23
[autohtml] => f
[alt_contenttype] => 
[comments] => 
[status] => 0
[compiledlimitation] => xyz
[acl_plugins] => lmn
[acls_updated] => 2012-05-28 16:49:02
[parameters] => N;
[custom_data] => abc
[target] => 
[capping] => 0
[block] => 0
[is_deleted] => 0
```

Now , the odd behavious that I noticed that allthough initially it is set as expected , but after sometime , when , it fetches the data from the memcache key , the **alt** key=>val pair is not present in the fetched array .

I am using

```
 set($key,$arrayName,3600); and get($key)
```

of the Memcache extension class.

Why is this happening with the **alt** key specifically , this key I have added to this array recently and since then this issue has been noticed .

Comment: I can't see this as a memcache issue given the way memcache stores data like this. Is it possible you're storing this array minus the alt key somewhere else in the code?

Answer (score 0):

A cache is just a temporary buffer and it can delete records, if it runs out of space, or the records expired. That is the expected behaviour. If you need a persistent storage, use a database.

Comment: Since the array is stored as serialized string, the whole string would be removed, not just the `alt` key part